# sorting in pandas not giving expected results

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Basic basic question but can't get it right.  I'm trying to sort by scores and then get the top name associated with the top score.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'score' :[1,5,7,999], 'name':['jack','jill','chris','kevin']})
df.sort_values(by= 'score', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df
df.name[0]
```

However with this approach I get Jack instead of Kevin since it seems to be going by the order the names appeared in the data frame creation.   What's the obvious thing I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when you access `df.name[0]`, it points to the index of the row (check out by calling `df.index`). The index value of the row where name is `jack` is `0`, since when you created the df the first instance was `jack`.

In order to access the first row on the sorted df, use `.iloc` for positional indexing (or `.loc` if you want a label-based indexing).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'score' :[1,5,7,999], 'name':['jack','jill','chris','kevin']})
df.sort_values(by= 'score', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df
df.name.iloc[0]
```

This returns `kevin`.

Answer (score 0):

The index can be restructured by [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).


In your case, execute below after sort_values would restructure index.

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .using `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.score.idxmax(),'name']

Out[5631]: 'kevin'
```